# downloading file from ftp server corrupted,

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, ftp

Im have a schema when upload file to ftp server its automatic encrypted and when download file its automatic decrypt the file . when i try to run the program, upload file to ftp server its success and file was encrypted. but when download file, sometimes it cant connected to ftp server (the idm showing process  just connecting), and sometimes it success download, but the file corrupted. what i miss? 
here i have the code :
prosesdownload.php (this class to dekrypt the file on the ftp server)

```
<html>
<?php
include 'ftpconfig.php';
include 'aes.php';
$file = $_GET['id'];
$fileFtp = 'ftp://'.$ftp_user_name.':'.$ftp_user_pass.'@'.$ftp_server;
$crypt = new aes_encryption();
$fileName = str_replace('.enc','',$fileFtp.'/'.$file);
$fileNamee = str_replace('.enc','',$file);
$enkrip = $crypt->decrypt_file($fileFtp.'/'.$file, $fileName);
if (!$enkrip) {
echo "Gagal";
}
else {
?>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
<h1><a href="download.php?id=<?php echo $fileNamee ?>">Click Here To Download File</a></h1>
<?php
} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and the download.php (to get the file was decrypted)

```
<html>
<?php
include 'ftpconfig.php';
$file = $_GET['id'];
$fileFtp = 'ftp://'.$ftp_user_name.':'.$ftp_user_pass.'@'.$ftp_server.'/'.$file;
?>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = "<?php echo $fileFtp?>"

        alert('<?php echo $fileFtp?>');
        window.location.href='delete.php?id=<?php echo $file ?>'

        </script>
    </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

what makes the file corrupted? the ftp server (filezilla) or the decrypt code?please give me your opinion, it will help me,

Comment: Test it in small independent steps.  Do files without encryption transfer correctly?  Do files that are encrypted locally encrypt/decrypt correctly?

Comment: i already try that, files without encryption transfer correct, and files encrypt decrypt correct, any idea whats going on?

Comment: So the downloaded (encrypted) file that is corrupted is different to the encrypted file on the server?

Comment: If you retry the download do you get file correctly?

Comment: when download on the server automatically decrypted, and file was already decrypted who was sent it to client.
yes, i get the file correctly sometimes, but sometimes i dont know why the file was downloaded corrupted.

Comment: OK, I understand now. Did you check what kind of corruption is that? Are random parts of the file wrong? Is the file truncated? Did you check the decrypted file on the server? Is it correct or same as the downloaded file (=with the same corruption)?

Comment: yes, the decrypted file on the server is same as the download file (size), sometimes corrupted sometimes no, did you have a clue?

Comment: Are you transferring it in ascii or binary mode?  ascii can corrupt:  http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/file-management/corrupt-file-ftp-transfer